# Nodetime profiler discrepancy

Tags: node.js, debugging, memory, profiling

I'm new to nodetime.com - why is the total time for a transaction (the time it takes for node to process a request) not the sum of the transaction's operations? Where has the other ~135 ms gone?

[image: nodetime screenshot]

Happy to provide any additional info. Thanks.